# Library missing compiling XBMC from source

Tags: debian, compiling, xbmc

Somewhere between the 13 and 13.1 releases I was no longer able to compile XBMC from source. I was able to compile v13 when it was first released (from the Gotham branch). Then, 13.1 was announced and I decided not to try the betas/RCs; so I have not attempted to compile those. When the final 13.1 version was released, I tried to compile that one, with the same procedure as I've used every time with success. But this time, it didn't work...

I'm failing in the "./configure" step with "could not find a required library". The command terminates with something like:

```
(...)
checking for TAGLIB... yes
checking for CDIO... yes
checking for LIBBLURAY... yes
checking for libbluray soname... libbluray.so.1
checking for bd_register_argb_overlay_proc in -lbluray... no
checking for library containing iconv_open... no
checking for library containing libiconv_open... no
configure: error: Could not find a required library. Please see the README for your platform.
```

Here's the full `config.log` file: http://pastebin.com/nGynLkX6

I'm not sure that's the problem but I manually downloaded, compiled and installed `libiconv` from http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/, it didn't seem to help though.

In case it's relevant, I always execute the following commands (in that specific order) to compile a new XBMC version:

```
git clean -xfd
git reset --hard
git pull --rebase

make -C lib/taglib
sudo make -C lib/taglib install

./bootstrap
./configure --disable-debug --disable-pulse --disable-vaapi --enable-goom
make

sudo make install
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE!**

I have upgraded zlib1g and now I was able to finish the configure step. However, compiling with make, eventually gives me errors on "undefined reference" to libiconv, libiconv_open and libiconv_close. Ideas?

Comment: What's the URL for the git repo you're downloading?

Comment: https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/

Comment: BTW, I went through the configuration and it worked for me, I had to install a LOT of packages and libraries to do this.

Comment: I must be missing some package update. The thing is, I'm on Debian Squeeze and most dependencies for this to work must come from Wheezy. I just need to find out which one I need to update from Wheezy to get it to work again. (I can't upgrade to Wheezy because I'm using OpenMediaVault which does not support Wheezy yet).

Comment: Yes that's the painful part of these types of packages that require dozens of libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update `zlib1g` and now it worked :)

For the record, here's what I said in the comments above and why I don't have everything updated:

> I must be missing some package update. The thing is, I'm on Debian
>   Squeeze and most dependencies for this to work must come from Wheezy.
>   I just need to find out which one I need to update from Wheezy to get
>   it to work again. (I can't upgrade to Wheezy because I'm using
>   OpenMediaVault which does not support Wheezy yet).

Another problem was that I had to do `make uninstall` on the manually downloaded `iconv` package because that was conflicting with something else.

Now I was successful :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the output from `./configure --help`. There are likely other options for disabling the requirements for the libraries that the make is showing you're missing.

```
checking for bd_register_argb_overlay_proc in -lbluray... no
checking for library containing iconv_open... no
checking for library containing libiconv_open... no
configure: error: Could not find a required library. Please see the README for your platform.
```

I'd start by disabling any of those and see if you're able to compile afterwards.

Comment: Do you mean one by one? :(

Comment: Just disabled everything that had a `--disable-*` from `./configure --help` and it still didn't work.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral - it definitely will compile, you'll have to use `apt-file` to figure out what libraries you're missing and install them. The README states what libraries you need to install too. But it definitely compiled w/o issue.

Comment: I updated my original question, please take a look.